# 301 or 303 redirect in html meta tag?

Tags: html, seo

Recently I have moved my content from oldURL to newURL and I want to attain 301 redirect(document moved permanently), to achieve that I have used new html appology page with meta tag having the new url and http-equip="Refresh", something like follows;

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url="newURL" />
```

I want to know that, will it return status code 301 or status code 303 ?

Also, if it is 303, please suggest me any better way that how should I achieve 301 redirect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know that, will it return status code 301 or status code 303 ?

No. Meta elements in an HTML document are not handled at the HTTP level.

The HTTP status will be whatever the HTTP headers say (probably 200).

Use HTTP for redirects, not Meta.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these two solutions. You can either :-

1. Create an htaccess file redirecting you to the new URL. There's more on how to do the task mentioned above [here](http://perishablepress.com/custom-http-errors-via-htaccess/).
2. You can create a small error template in your old URL stating that it has been moved and post the link to your new URL.

In my opinion, I would recommend you doing the former because the user will not know the transition between pages.